# Is it feasible to set the memory usage for PyODBC?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am working on a project that connects to SQL Server to execute thousands of Stored Procedures and to retrieve the result sets.

I set fast_executemany = True and use executemany to quickly go through all the Sprocs. But upon retrieving the result sets, I found out that although it is fast for the first 30-40 result sets, it gets progressively slower to retrieve the rest.

Is it because the first 30-40 sets are cached in memory but for the rest, the cursor object is going back to the remote database to fetch the data? If this is the case, can I increase/control the memory usage by PyODBC so that all the result sets can be cached as long as the total RAM allows?

Comment: But would that help you? If you first cache the database before executing the query, you're simply loosing time during caching instead of during querying, right? Have you tried executing everything twice in one run, and comparing the performances? Also note that there are many, many caching mechanisms between the db and your screen, the problem could be somewhere else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Is it because the first 30-40 sets are cached in memory but for the rest, the cursor object is going back to the remote database to fetch the data?"*

Yes, but they are cached on the server, not the client. When you start running a batch that represents "thousands of Stored Procedures" you also start generating result sets. Those result sets are buffered on the server until they are retrieved by the client. That buffer size is limited, and if it gets full then control is returned to the client and the batch is suspended until the client retrieves some result sets to free up some space.

As noted in

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/827575/sql-server-does-not-finish-execution-of-a-large-batch-of-sql-statement

> If you are executing a large batch with multiple result sets, SQL Server fills that output buffer until it hits an internal limit and cannot continue to process more result sets. At that point, control returns to the client. When the client starts to consume the result sets, SQL Server starts to execute the batch again because there is now available memory in the output buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How can I increase the buffer size in MS SQL DB? Could you point me to some links? So I can work with our DBA to make necessary changes.

Comment: Also in pyodbc, cursor.executemany returns a set of iterable cursors. So when does the client consume the result sets? Is it at the end of executemany? Or is it when I loop through cursor.nextset() and run cursor.fetchall() In each loop? Many thanks!